# Алгоритмы бинарный поиск

Tags: алгоритм, бинарный-поиск

Есть 2 массива, отсортированные один в порядке убывания, второй в порядке возрастания. При бинарном поиске у обоих же будет асимптотика O(log2n) не важно же в каком порядке отсортирован массив? Я правильно понимаю что асимптотика не изменится?

Comment: Конечно, нет...

Comment: Правильно понимаете